# How do I setup host-only VMWare to use the host's DHCP server?

Tags: vmware, virtualization

If I have a VMware box with host-only networking, what is the IP of the host, or how do I connect to the host?

I'm testing some DHCP stuff and I would like a fresh VMware box to only communicate with the (poorly configured) DHCP server of the host, on which I am working. Any advice on how to do that is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Virtual Network Editor to **Uncheck** the option "Use local DHCP service to distribute IP addresses to VMs" and changing from host-only networking into bridged networking should do the trick.

If you don't want to bridge the VMWare machine onto the rest of your real network you should be able to stay with vmnet1(host-only) and manually assign the IP address of the machine using it's operating system settings to an IP address on the same subnet of the host. You can test if the guest is now properly located on the host's subnet via the ping command.

Here's a picture to illustrate:

http://popravak.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/snaghtml9e6c406.png

default network adapters are:

vmnet1=Host-only

vmnet8=NAT(aka shared)

Comment: This didn't work, I had to select "custom specific virtual network" in the config of the network adapter. But thanks for upvoting ^__^